# pandas calculate percent change based on specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with a set of numbers that I would like to calculate the percent change. The df is

```
    2   3
0   1   1
1   2   2
2   3   3
3   4   4
4   5   5
5   6   6
```

The command I have been using is `df.per_change(periods=)` where I would like the periods be the column names, i.e. 2 and 3 respectively. The desired output would look something like this.

```
           2     3
0        NaN   NaN
1        NaN   NaN
2   2.000000   NaN
3   1.000000     3
4   0.666667   1.5
5   0.500000     1
```

The main issue I have is when I try and input periods into `df.pct_change(periods=)`, it only allows a specific number, not a value  based on a specific column. Are there any workarounds or other ways to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try with `concat` after for loop

```
newdf=pd.concat([df[x].pct_change(periods = int(x)) for x in df.columns],axis=1)
Out[47]: 
          2    3
0       NaN  NaN
1       NaN  NaN
2  2.000000  NaN
3  1.000000  3.0
4  0.666667  1.5
5  0.500000  1.0
```

Or

```
newdf = df.apply(lambda x : x.pct_change(periods = int(x.name)), axis=0 )
Out[64]: 
          2    3
0       NaN  NaN
1       NaN  NaN
2  2.000000  NaN
3  1.000000  3.0
4  0.666667  1.5
5  0.500000  1.0
```